# How to replace the third character in number to other character

Tags: sed, awk

IPS parameter include diff IP address as:

```
IPS="192.9.200.12-14 172.17.200.12-89 12.21.1.10-25 127.0.0.1-127"
```

I want to replace the third “.” In the IP address number to “,”

How to achieve this by `sed` or `awk` ?

Example:

```
echo $IPS | sed ……..
```

the requested output

```
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in the shell:

```
IPS='192.9.200.12-14 172.17.200.12-89 12.21.1.10-25 127.0.0.1-127'
echo $(IFS=\ .; printf %s.%s.%s,%s\  $IPS)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

But a better way - one in which you can actually work with an array - is to turn it into a function:

```
iprng() (IFS=.;for ip do printf %s.%s.%s,%s\\n $ip; done)
iprng $IPS
```

#### OUTPUT

```
192.9.200,12-14
172.17.200,12-89
12.21.1,10-25
127.0.0,1-127
```

or...

```
echo $(iprng $IPS)
```

#### OUTPUT

```
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

As you can see, it is practically the same thing that is done elsewhere with `awk` except that it is done more simply and without invoking another executable.

Answer (score 2):

Match everything up to the last dot and remember it in a group:

```
$ echo $IPS | sed 's/\([^ ]*\)\./\1,/g'
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the first and second groups that match the octets of an IPaddress, and return those with the comma character in lieu of the dot before the range:

```
echo ${IPS}|perl -pe 's!(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\.(\d+-\d+\s+)!$1,$2!g'
```

Using Perl we can represent digits with `\d` and whitespace with `\s'.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `perl`, you can:

```
echo "${IPS}" | perl -pe 's/\./(++$c%3==0)?",":"."/ge'
```

Comment: that takes care of only the first IP

Comment: @1_CR: I read the post in mobile and seen the input was in multi line. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk, set record separator to one or more spaces, field separator to `.` and so on.

```
echo "$IPS" | awk -vRS='[ ]+' -F'.' -vOFS='.' '{x=$NF;NF--;printf "%s,%s ", $0,x}'
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

Or

```
echo "$IPS" | awk -vRS='[ ]+'   '{$0=gensub(/\./, ",", 3); printf "%s%s", $0, RT}'
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that makes use of `sed`. It identifies blocks within the strings that occur like so:

```
.<digits>-
```

When found, `sed` will remember the digits & <kbd>-</kbd> pieces and swap out the preceding <kbd>.</kbd> with a <kbd>,</kbd>.

```
$ echo "$IPS" | sed 's/\.\([[:digit:]]\+-\)/,\1/g'
```

#### Example

```
$ echo "$IPS" | sed 's/\.\([[:digit:]]\+-\)/,\1/g'
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below perl command,

```
$ echo '192.9.200.12-14 172.17.200.12-89 12.21.1.10-25 127.0.0.1-127' | perl -pe 's/[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\K\./,/g'
192.9.200,12-14 172.17.200,12-89 12.21.1,10-25 127.0.0,1-127
```